# how can I get same effect Jquery $().slideToggle() from zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have a code in Jquery as below;

```
$("#id").slideToggle('fast');
$("#id").promise().done($('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 200));
```

I start to use Zepto js instead of Jquery, so now I'm using below code,

```
$("#id").toggle();
```

How can I get the same effect like Jquery code from Zepto, in zepto .promise() is not defined

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try callback function.